# Infinispan 8.1 Java version - documentation vs reality

Tags: java, version, infinispan

I am trying to update a server app with a new infinispan (8.1 the latest stable release). For corporate reasons I have to use the lowest Java version possible.

According to the FAQ:
http://infinispan.org/docs/8.1.x/faqs/faqs.html#_what_version_of_java_does_infinispan_need_to_run_does_infinispan_need_an_application_server_to_run

It is ok to use Java 7. But according to the exception I get:

**Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/infinispan/notifications/Listener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0**

major.minor = 52 is as far as I understand Java 8 - so that means they compiled it using Java 8 compiler instead of Java 7.

Are there some infinispan 8.1 versions that are compiled with Java 7?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that document was not updated when we released Infinispan 8. 
Infinispan 8 relies on Java 8 features like streams, lambdas, Optional, CompletableFuture, etc so it is impossible to make it work with Java 7.
Bear in mind that Java 7 has been EOL since April 2015.

I have created an issue to track this together with a pull request https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-6313

I apologise for the confusion